# Sprinkler: Water leaking from the black box with the screws

Tags: sprinkler-system

After the winter storm when I turned on my water valve for my sprinkler, water gushed from the top. I notice the black top was cracked and I could take it off with my hand. Inside was filled with water and the rubber plastic ring and white and red plastic piece was floating at the top. Is this something easy to fix? [image]

Comment: Can you get us a side view of the thing you broke?

Comment: It’s the bonnet box that was cracked and the water was leaking out of it. It was a winter storm here so I believe it must have frozen over since the top part wasn’t drained. This post won’t let me add more than one picture I’m not sure why.

Comment: upload additional images to imgur.com and post the links in a comment. Someone will embed them for you.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be the backflow preventer and you may be able to find replacement parts for that specific make/model at a local irrigation supply house.

Otherwise, you'll need to replace it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t know what the actual item was called so this helped a lot.  I did see the individual parts for sale online so I’ll order it to see if that solves it!